Random piece on ground
I found a random piece of mega bloks on the ground and was wondering was set it's from. I've never had a mega bloks set so i don't know anything.

Welcome to Bricks.SE.  Despite the clear picture you took of this piece it will be almost impossible for anyone to guess that the missing bits are.  The online databases that are available for LEGO don't have equivalents for megabloks or other clone brands.  If anyone can figure it out, it will be someone on this site.  But don't expect a miracle.

This is a figure stand as used in the Megabloks Halo line,
as pointed out in the comment by Chicks, without additional pieces it's very hard to identify the exact set

